# Pre-lock hook tortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, hook, tortoisesvn

I am looking for a pre-lock hook for TortoiseSVN. Before locking, the script will make update of a file which is locking. I can't see anything ready to implement. Because I am a mechanical engineer, I am not proficient in writing scripts. Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site deals with concrete programming problems. If you want anybody to help you need to [edit] your post and share at least a [mre] of what you're trying to achieve. Please also explain what problem you're trying to solve. Is it a TortoiseSVN *client side* hook script you're talking about? Normal hook scripts run on the server where "update before lock" does not make sense.

Comment: It is client TortoiseSVN hook script.